# What's different about Android mobile browsers?

Tags: android, mobile

I have a web page that I have specifically set up to display reasonably on mobiles. If I go to it from my desktop, with the window size set to something like a mobile (or full screen), it loads quickly, and works as far as my QA has gone. If I load it from the same server on my Android mobile, which has a pretty ancient version of the OS - Gingerbread - it falls to pieces.

My desktop is connected to the Internet by a USB modem that uses the local 3G network. My mobile connects to the same network. If I tether the mobile to my desktop, the network performance is as good as, or better than when it is connected normally, so the mobile is clearly receiving 3G effectively, and it is in the same room.

On the mobile, this seems to apply across the stock browser, Firefox, and Dolphin. If anything, the Gingerbread stock browser seems to do best!

What am I, or what is Android doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you use USB Tethering or Portable Wifi HotSpot, you will get 3G speed as well. Because, if you are using in mobile, there will be minimum of 200MB RAM which will not support much performance. So do connect with your desktop with USB Tethering to get more 3G Performance.

Comment: But it's the mobile performance I am concerned about - that's the target audience for the page. I know it works fine on my desktop.

So I should change my design so as to use less memory and a number of smaller pages that trade memory for bandwidth?

At present it is one big page, with separate elements displayed or hidden, which I guess is memory intensive.

Comment: Yes. It's upto to the mobile you are using. If you are using high configuration Mobile like Samsung Galaxy S Series, you can get that much speed.